# How is the Wigner characteristic function defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

When defining the Wigner characteristic function of a state represented by the density matrix $\rho$, I have seen various sources [including https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3234] first define the Weyl operator
$$D_\xi = \exp(i\mathbf{x}^T\Omega\xi)$$
and then use this operator to present the characteristic function as
$$\chi(\xi) = Tr[\rho D_\xi].$$
What I don't understand is how $\chi(\xi)$ characterizes $\rho$ at all. Isn't $Tr[\rho D_\xi] = \langle D_\xi \rangle$, which is independent of the choice of density matrix? What am I missing to see that there is a unique $\chi$ for each $\rho$.

Comment: what sources please... and please define your notation.

Comment: The expectation of an observable *depends* on the choice of the state (density matrix). An easy example is to consider the expectation of the spin operator with respect to either $\lvert \uparrow \rangle \langle \uparrow \rvert$ or $\lvert \downarrow \rangle \langle \downarrow \rvert$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wigner function is also called *non-commutative Fourier transform*, precisely because it shares many similarities with the standard Fourier transform of a probability measure.

In fact, the Weyl operator plays the noncommutative role of the character $e^{i\xi \cdot x}$ in the commutative case, and the density matrix is a noncommutative probability measure.

The analogy is foremostly introduced because the noncommutative Fourier transform characterizes uniquely, as in the commutative case, a given density matrix. This result is known as noncommutative Bochner's theorem, and was proved by I. Segal in the fifties in the more general context of regular states of the algebras of canonical commutation relations.